# Распарсить тег script python

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста, уже замучался. С помощью BeautifulSoup нахожу тег script с нужной мне информацией и не могу его распарсить. То есть у меня не получается извлечь из него весь тескт чтобы с ним потом работать. метод .text не работает с ним (по-чемуто).

```
text = soup.find_all('script')[1].text # так не работает

text = soup.find_all('script')[1]      # так выводит на печать: <script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"ghj", some text....</script>   Но это  не парсится.
```

Как мне получить в чистом виде всю текстовую информацию внутри тега script ?

Comment: Что значит «не работает»?

Comment: print(text) выводит '' (пустые кавычки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался! Может кому-то будет полезно. Так работает:

```
text = soup.find_all('script')[1].string.strip()
```

А что-бы работать потом с этими данными нужно импортировать import json
и данные преобразовать в json

```
data = json.loads(text)
```